# invalid type assertion: cannot convert os.Stdout to interface type io.ReadWriter?

Tags: go, types, compilation, assert

I'm refering to gopl sample code as below:

```
v := os.Stdout
v2 = v.(io.ReadWriter)
```

But go 1.13 will a report compilation error on it:

```
invalid type assertion: v.(io.ReadWriter) (non-interface type *os.File on left)
```

I supposed that as long as Stdout is a writer, this conversion to ReadWriter should trigger a runtime type conversion error, but in fact, a compilation error is reported.

I wish to know in what conditions, type assertion/conversion will fail in compile time, and under what condition it will fail in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `io.ReadWriter(os.Stdout)` to do that as you already have an concrete pointer to a struct (alternatively also works with structs).

Type assertions such as `v.(*SomeConcreteType)` are used when `v` implements some interface and you want to convert it to a concrete type (struct/pointer...). You're trying to do it the other way around, which is why the compiler complains about the non-interface type.

That does not really make sense as the only thing you're doing is limiting the methods you can call on `v2`. You can still pass `v` to a method that accepts a `io.ReadWriter` without converting anything as it implements that interface.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `v` is a concrete type `*FILE` and for a type assertion of form `i.(T)`, `i` must be an `interface` and `T` is type/interface, so your code has compile error

This should do what you except but it won't trigger runtime error because `os.Stdout` satisfies `io.ReadWriter` interface

```
var v interface{} = os.Stdout
v2 := v.(io.ReadWriter)
```

> under what condition it will fail in runtime

If interface `i` does not hold/Satisfy requirement for type `T`, the statement will trigger a panic.

For Example these statements will trigger panic because `os.Stdout` which has type `*FILE` doesn't satisfy requirements for io.ByteScanner

```
var v interface{} = os.Stdout
v2 := v.(io.ByteScanner)
```